# UIScrollView or UIPageViewController for IOS 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I have searched this site and many others, but could not find an up to date answer for this.

I am trying to replicate the multi paged view of the twitter app. So I just can't really figure out what is the correct -or practical- way to implement this.

UIScrollView with page controls or UIPageViewController? Every page is going to be a table view. Also, if I should use scroll view with page controls, do I still instantiate several view controllers and use their views, or do I just use several table views?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `UIPageViewController`

Here is a good tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bltsDG2ENQ

Comment: I have already tired both and chose one. This answer is obviously not very helpful considering 4 months have passed, but I will still accept it to show that I appreciate the effort.

Comment: Tesekkurler :) . What did you choose?

Comment: Önemli değil, I chose scroll view with paging to make title transitions easier. I didn't have many view controllers anyway so it is not that crippling performance-wise

Comment: How does it make title transitions easier?

Comment: I implemented something like the old twitter app and I wanted to slide the titles in and out as the corresponding views came into place. When used page view controller it was hard to get content offset as it reseted itself to 320 (Second page, in iPhone 5) whenever the sliding animation finished. So it was impossible to equate the scroll views content offset to the scroll view (which holds the titles) in the navigation bar. If you know a work around for that I would like to hear it, it may help me in future projects.